# Displaying the nodes of binary search tree which belongs depth path of the tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree, depth

I have a method in `Tree` class which calculates the depth of a binary search tree.

My additional task is to, while calculating the depth of the tree, also store (or keep in some way) the nodes which are on this path (from the root to the most distanced leaf).

For instance, consider the following tree:

```
      10  
     /  \
    6    13 
   / \     \    
  4   9     14  
 /   /
3   8
```

I need to produce the nodes: 8,9,6,10

I have this `Node` class:

```
class Node {

private:
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    int value;
public:
   Node(int v = 0) : left(NULL) , right(NULL) , value(v) { cout << "Node construcotr      " << endl;}

    Node *getLeft() {return this->left;}
    void setLeft(Node *n) {this->left = n;}
    Node *getRight() {return this->right;}
    void setRight(Node *n) {this->right = n;}
    int getVal() {return this->value;}

};
```

And here is the relevant part of the `Tree` class:

```
class Tree {

private:
    Node* root;
    vector<int> vec; /*.....*/

int calcDepth(Node *n)
{ 
 if (n == NULL)
     return 0;
 else 
 {
     int ld = calcDepth(n->getLeft());
     int rd = calcDepth(n->getRight());

     if (ld > rd)
     {
         if (n->getLeft() != NULL) vec.push_back(n->getLeft()->getVal());
         return ld + 1;
     }
     else 
     {
         if (n->getRight() != NULL) vec.push_back(n->getRight()->getVal());
         return rd + 1;
     }
 }
} // end of calcDepth
```

At the moment it gives me partial solution (excluding the root and taking into account node which are not part of that path).

Can someone help me fix this code?

In addition, any other comments about the implementation will also be great.

Comment: Can you show us the actual output your program generates (along with the expected output, if it's not the same as the given example)? Note that it's helpful to provide an [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example)](http://sscce.org) (with the emphasis on self-contained), so we can run the program and see the results for ourselves, and test our changes to see if they work. Also note that these issues are typically fairly easily figured out by writing down what the program is supposed to do at each step for some given example and writing code from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that when it calls a `push_back`, it's one of the nodes in the path. Since your current algorithm adds nodes for every node.

```
class Tree {

private:
    Node* root;
    vector<int> vec; /*.....*/

int calcDepth(Node *n,int isInPath)
{ 
 if (n == NULL)
     return 0;
 else 
 {
     int ld = calcDepth(n->getLeft(),0);
     int rd = calcDepth(n->getRight(),0);

         if(isInPath){
         vec.push_back(n->getVal());
         if (ld > rd)
         {
             calcDepth(n->getLeft(),isInPath);
             return ld + 1;
         }
         else 
         {   
             calcDepth(n->getRight(),isInPath);
             return rd + 1;
         }
        }
    return max(ld+1,rd+1);
 }

} // end of calcDepth
```

I've added a variable `isInPath`, that is 1 if the current node is in the path, and 0 if it's not. You will call this with the root and 1.

It finds the maximum of the two and only then calls with `isInPath == 1`. And with this method, only nodes with `isInPath == 1` will be added to the vector.

I haven't tested it out but it should work. You can also create this as a private function and then a public one with only the node value.

Note: This has `O(N^2)` complexity. To make it in `O(N)` you can memorize the values so you don't compute them 2 times.

Comment: @ Dragos Florian Ristache: Thanks allot Dragos. Yet I did not understand your solution for the O(N) complexity, can you be more specific. In addition , I need to change a little the prototype of the function so it will receive (from the calling function ) the vector to store the nodes of the longest path.  Do you mean by memorize that we will need some extra vectors for the values ?? Will be great if you can change your solution for the one with the better complexity (in run time) , again , if it requires more space - it is possible for provide it.

Comment: @ Dragos Florian Ristache: The new prototype is int calcDepth(Node *n,int isInPath, vector<int> &vec) so that vec is provided from the calling function (main or whatever...)